# Physics Curricula of 19th Century French Universities?

Tags: physics, academia, education, 19th-century, france

What were the physics curricula for 19th century French universities?

I am looking for something akin to [this distribution of courses at the *École Polytechnique*](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044079809943;view=1up;seq=400), but for other French universities, like the *École Normale*.

Comment: @scaaahu: Perhaps. More so than [my other academic history question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19260/9425).

Comment: I'd write an e-mail to the university itself, I'm sure most of them still have records about the curricula from the 19th century.

Comment: Curricula for *all* courses?